# Avoid stretching slented borders on responsive SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there a way, possibly without JS, do generate a responsive SVG where the slanted border does not stretch with the width? Please do not reply with "use CSS" because I need to create a complex mask that is simply not possible with CSS alone.

```css
body {padding: 20px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
 <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="60" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350.47 32.42">
 <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs>
 <title>test</title>
 <polygon class="cls-1" points="0.93 31.91 21.34 0.5 333.39 0.5 349.62 31.91 0.93 31.91"/>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The short answer is no.  You can kludge it in certain circumstances - for example the "pencil" example linked in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524865/scale-different-parts-of-svg-file-differently).  Otherwise you will need to do something like create two SVGs representing the left and right ends. And a third to form the stretchy middle section.

Answer (score 0):

change `preserveAspectRatio` to `"xMaxYMax"` to avoid stretching and `height` to `"100%"` let the rectangle grow if needed for large screen

```css
body {padding: 20px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
 <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax" width="100%" height="100%" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350.47 32.42">
 <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs>
 <title>test</title>
 <polygon class="cls-1" points="0.93 31.91 21.34 0.5 333.39 0.5 349.62 31.91 0.93 31.91"/>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need the height to stay the same, I have a text inside that must be of a certain size in both desktop/mobile.