# Scale an Svg withouth stretching a part of it

Tags: html, css, svg

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524865/scale-different-parts-of-svg-file-differently) but I think it is "too complex" in my case and I would like to know if there is some easier way.

I have an **svg path** (the darker one) and I would like to **fill all the screen (height 100%)** when it's resized but **without stretching the top curve**.

Filling all the screen is not a problem, but doing it without stretching the top curve is and I would like to **"extend" the rectangle** below it.

[image]

Comment: you'd need to update the sizes and positions of the elements on resize. SVG won't do this automatically for you.

Comment: I think you're probably going to need to split your SVG into separate paths (the curved part being one, the box being another) and then only resize the box path proportional to the screen size, rather than the entire SVG.

Comment: @indextwo i thought too

Comment: @RobertLongson i can't without stretching it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right and bottom edges are flat.  So there is a very simple solution in this case.

Just make your shape (path) extend far off the right and bottom of the SVG, and let the shape be clipped by the edges of the SVG.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <path id="top" d="M 0,0 L 50,0 Q 70,0, 90 20 Q 110,40 130,40 H 4000 V 4000 H 0 Z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this Is the final solution i took, but this seems not so performing