# How can I make this SVG polygon "wedge" always have 45 degree ends?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to make this wedge shape has 45 degree angles at both ends.

[image]

As the size of its containing div changes, or the page is zoomed, that angle changes:

[image]

Here's my (abbreviated) code:

```html
<div class="relative">
  <svg class="h-16p top-0 left-0 absolute w-full fill-current" viewBox="0 0 100 4" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 95,5 5,5" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

I'm using tailwindCSS - for those not familiar those classes translate to:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
fill: currentColor;
height: 16px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the aspect ratio then specifying preserveAspectRatio="none" isn't going to be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524865/scale-different-parts-of-svg-file-differently