# How to expand only the center of a SVG? (keep the bottom and top)

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design

Based on this question: [Scale different parts of SVG file differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524865/scale-different-parts-of-svg-file-differently) (but the answers use only the pencil example, that serves for X (width) images and not Y)

Here is the sample SVG:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="193pt" height="25pt" viewBox="0 0 193 25" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#ffffffff">
<path fill="#ffffff" opacity="1.00" d=" M 186.39 0.00 L 193.00 0.00 L 193.00 5.57 C 191.69 2.83 189.20 1.00 186.39 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#ffffff" opacity="1.00" d=" M 186.04 25.00 C 188.92 24.18 191.42 22.39 193.00 19.83 L 193.00 25.00 L 186.04 25.00 Z" />
</g>
<g id="#339933ff">
<path fill="#339933" opacity="1.00" d=" M 5.66 0.00 L 186.39 0.00 C 189.20 1.00 191.69 2.83 193.00 5.57 L 193.00 7.03 C 139.67 6.97 86.33 7.01 33.00 7.00 C 28.05 6.92 23.02 7.43 18.13 6.41 C 12.54 3.77 6.35 3.06 0.48 1.30 C 2.20 0.85 3.93 0.41 5.66 0.00 Z" />
<path fill="#339933" opacity="1.00" d=" M 18.02 18.04 C 76.34 17.95 134.67 18.03 193.00 18.00 L 193.00 19.83 C 191.42 22.39 188.92 24.18 186.04 25.00 L 24.52 25.00 C 21.40 23.80 18.43 21.60 18.02 18.04 Z" />
</g>
<g id="#000000ff">
<path fill="#000000" opacity="1.00" d=" M 18.13 6.41 C 23.02 7.43 28.05 6.92 33.00 7.00 C 86.33 7.01 139.67 6.97 193.00 7.03 L 193.00 18.00 C 134.67 18.03 76.34 17.95 18.02 18.04 C 17.91 14.16 17.99 10.28 18.13 6.41 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

I would like to place this SVG on an div and, when increasing the height of this div, that the black (center) part of this image could expand accordingly.
It would produce an speech bubble/balloon fully made in SVG instead of CSS, fully customizable and responsive.